# How to create setRepeating in alarmManager for morning?

Tags: android

I have a list of items that i want to launch a notification for just about everyday. But not in the middle of the night when the user is possibly sleep.

Probably any time in the a.m after 8 o'clock.

I know i will need to use this using the AlarmManager.

I am pretty familiar with using the AlarmManager.

I just dont know what my

```
AlarmManager.setRepeating();
```

Method will look like for what i am trying to do.

How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try reading the documentation?

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

A couple of hints. When you get the current date, you can convert that into how many ms that is passed epoch time. In order to figure out what that time would be in 1h you have to convert 1h to milliseconds.

```
My time = x;
```

where x is a particular date/time in ms, since epoch time.

if I'm interested in converting 1h to milliseconds then i would do it like this (1000ms = 1s)

```
1h = 60m = 60 * 60 = 3600s = 3,600,000ms
```

so,

```
x = x+3,600,000
```

This will offset x by an hour.

There is a bunch of constants that you can use in AlarmManager.

Sample command:

```
AlarmManager.setRepeating((type), (specific date in ms after epoch), (repeating interval), (The intent to fire))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working code. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes.

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
...
```

Code:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
         wl.acquire();

         // Put here YOUR code.
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         wl.release();
     }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 10), pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }
}
```

Comment: How/from Where is this SetAlarm called. Is it a callback/lifecycle method.

Comment: As I read the doc, using AlarmManager.set() will result in a one-time alarm.  If you want AlarmManager to send the broadcast "every 10 minutes", it looks like AlarmManager.setRepeating() is the method to use.